# Body color changes to white when opening mat-modal?

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, angular-material

[image]

Body color of the page is changing to white when i open the mat-modal
initially i have

```
body{
    background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
```

which is there in the styles.css but this page need new body color so i am doing below code in ngOninit()

```
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.backgroundColor =
      "#061325";
```

i tried adding a backDropClass when opening the mat-modal but that doesn't work, i could see this is happening when there is a scroll, page doesn't change when height is 100%

Comment: you shouldnt be manipulating the backgroundColor like that. are you trying to change the background page's color when modal opens or the the modal's color itself ?

Comment: @ihorbond  am changing the page color in the ngOnint,i am not changing the modal color its white

Comment: you can change the component's ViewEncapsulation and change body's background color in the component's .scss